area light lighting unevenly in a scene evee
i am trying to light a symmetrical box in a scene as background however the area light lighting it unevenly (over lit on right)

On the left it behaves as the way expected however on the right it over lights the scene

Hello could you please share your file, I can't reproduce the same problem with an area light

Maybe try setting the scale to 1, ans set Shape to Rectangle ? I'm not sure if that could be the issue.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sNfDuwxu76os0P_fC9uB3UbPV5Sp6Iwt/view?usp=sharing - the file is here

You forgot to include your image textures in your blend file, so it's hard to tell for 100% certainty. But shader normals can definitely give such results, and you can see yourself that unplugging the normal map node from the Principled BSDF "fixes" the issue.
First, make sure you have a valid normal map, and whether it is object or tangent space:


Credit: glsl - How To Convert World Space Normal To Tangent Space? - Game Development Stack Exchange

Your image textures nodes for roughness and normal have their color management set to sRGB. The only kind of maps that should be left with that are ones that directly affect color, such as base color / albedo maps or emission. Other ones should be set to non-color for Blender to interpret them correctly. And in the case of a normal map, it could be the cause of your specific issue.
So try to set your rough and normal image textures to non-color color management, and it probably will fix the issue:

And seeing the name mentions "dx", maybe you have a DirectX format normal map, which need to have its Y channel inverted in Blender who is based on OpenGL. It's a bit had to tell if you don't know the shape supposed to be represented. When looking a normal from top to bottom, OpenGL uses green (Y) to show upward slopes and purple for downwards slopes.


Credit: cycles render engine - DirectX vs. OpenGL normal maps - Blender Stack Exchange

Or look at the final surface, moving a light around it to see if bumps look like bumps and holes like holes. If not, cycles render engine - DirectX vs. OpenGL normal maps - Blender Stack Exchange
